# how to transpose multiple level pandas dataframe based only on outer index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, hierarchical-data, transpose

the below is my dataframe with two level indexing. I want 'only' the outer index to be transposed as columns. My desired output would be 2X2 dataframe instead of a 4X1 dataframe as is the case now. Can any of you please help?

```
        0
0    0  232

     1  3453

1    0  443

     1  3241
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given you have the multi index you can use unstack() on level 0.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)])
df = pd.DataFrame([[1],[2],[3],[4]] , index=index, columns=[0])

print df.unstack(level=[0])


   0   
   0  1
0  1  3
1  2  4
```

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this would be to reset the index and then pivot the table indexing on the `level_1` of the index, and using `level_0` as the columns and `0` as the values. Example -

```
df.reset_index().pivot(index='level_1',columns='level_0',values=0)
```

Demo -

```
In [66]: index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)])

In [67]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1],[2],[3],[4]] , index=index, columns=[0])

In [68]: df
Out[68]:
     0
0 0  1
  1  2
1 0  3
  1  4

In [69]: df.reset_index().pivot(index='level_1',columns='level_0',values=0)
Out[69]:
level_0  0  1
level_1
0        1  3
1        2  4
```

Later on, if you want you can set the `.name` attribute for the `index` as well as the `columns` to empty string or whatever you want , if you don't want the `level_*` there.